# Read xml with Dataset with xml node attributes as a part of parent table

Tags: xml, ado.net, dataset, xsd, xml-attribute

I have this xml

```
<root>
<employee>
<firstname>Francis</firstname>
<lastname>Ferns</lastname>
<email protected=\"1\"/>
</employee>
</root>
```

This when being read from an **DataSet** reads two datables where another table gets added for the email . This is how the dataset visual looks like.

[image: Employee email table]
[image: email employee table]

Instead of reading the attributed column **protected** in another table i would like it to be apart of the **employee** table itself with the protected column preceded with a **"."** 
and the employee table.

Is there in any way i could define the dataset schema so that so that all attributes be read as a part of the parent table ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Infer On

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ds = New DataSet
    ds.ReadXml("c:\test.xml")

    ds.Tables("Employee").Columns.Add("protected", GetType(String))
    For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables("Employee").Rows
        row("Protected") = row.GetChildRows(ds.Relations(0))(0)("Protected")
    Next

    ds.Tables("Email").Constraints.Clear()
    ds.Tables("Employee").Constraints.Clear()
    ds.Relations.Clear()
    ds.Tables.Remove("email")
End Sub

End Class
```